# Xamarin Forms Bind Array element inside listView

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, binding

need to ask you a hand with this one.
I'm currently developing a Xamarin Forms solution using MVVM and i'm in a new situation right now.

I've got a listView with items made by this class

```
 public class City
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<string> Words{ get; } = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" };
}
```

What I want to achieve is to display a label text created using the `Words` list elements indicized by `Key`. Something like

```
Words[Key]
```

Example

```
 <ListView
        ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">

                    <Label Text="{Binding Words[Key]}"
                        FontSize="18"
                        TextColor="Black"
                        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />        
                </StackLayout>

                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The label text binding doesn't work, but tecnically is what i need to achieve. For example, if i use `Words[0]` it will work and returns 'One'

My ViewModel is pretty simple.

```
 public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<City> Cities { get; set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        Cities = GetCities();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<City> GetCities()
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<City>
        {
            new City {Key = 1, Value = "Mumbai"},
            new City {Key = 2, Value = "New York"},
            new City {Key = 3, Value = "Milan"},
            new City {Key = 4, Value = "Rome"}
        };
    }
}
```

Do i need to create a property for indexing? In my opinion the problem is that i'm inside a list and already have an index to use.

Thanks for help guys

Comment: Setting `ItemsSource` will automatically do this for you. You don't have to specifically give each element to ViewCell. Just set `Text="{Binding Value}"` and it shows the list with same order as your `ObservableCollection`. Also fire `OnPropertyChanged` on ObservableCollection's set method probably use a backing field

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a little mistake. I wanted to write Values[Key] because I don't want the Value property, what I want is display a List element value. I update the question changing names for better understanding

Comment: In this case you can make use of [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters). Take a look, if you still have any questions, update with your implementation of converter

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your model :

```
 public class City
    {
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public List<string> Words { get; } = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" };

        public string myValue
        {
            get
            {
                return Words[Key];
            }
            set {}
        }
    }
```

And in your `.xmal`,  just set `Text="{Binding myValue}"` and it will display a list element value of Words.